# How to upload the siacs HttpUploadComponent for file sharing in openfire localhost

Tags: chat, openfire

I am implementing the chat appliation using https://github.com/siacs/Conversations in android. There are no image sharing for group chat thats why It required the HTTP Upload component on openfire server (https://github.com/siacs/HttpUploadComponent). I made the changes in config.yml as per required. I am able to connected but in android eu:siacs:conversations:http:upload" not coming in feature list.

config.yml looks like below:-

```
component_jid: upload.andreis-mac-mini-2.local
component_secret: test
component_port: 5275

storage_path : /Users/enovate/Documents/Jagdish/Test

whitelist:
 # andreis-mac-mini-2.local
 # - someotherdomain.tld
 # - dude@domain.tld
max_file_size: 20971520 #20MiB

http_address: 127.0.0.1 #use 0.0.0.0 if you don't want to use a proxy
http_port: 8080
# http_keyfile: /etc/ssl/private/your.key
# http_certfile: /etc/ssl/certs/your.crt

get_url: http://andreis-mac-mini-2.local
put_url: http://andreis-mac-mini-2.local

expire_interval: 82800  #time in secs between expiry runs (82800 secs = 23 hours). set to '0' to disable
expire_maxage: 2592000  #files older than this (in secs) get deleted by expiry runs (2592000 = 30 days)
user_quota_hard: 104857600   #100MiB. set to '0' to disable rejection on uploads over hard quota
user_quota_soft: 78643200    #75MiB. set to '0' to disable deletion of old uploads over soft quota an expiry runs
```

If anyone have idea. Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Any workaround for this problem you found ?